# How would generate a Markov matrix from the graph below?

Tags: cytoscape

I am using CytoScape software. It has the ability to create a MCL Cluster automatically but I am having difficulties seeing the Associated Matrix. Does anyone know how to get that using Cytospace?

[mcl cluster generated using clustermaker2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ir2h.png)

Answer (score 0):

The clusterMaker2 app for Cytoscape performs MCL Clustering, but it does not provide output for intermediate steps, like the initial matrix of the network. However, there is an app for Cytoscape that can export a matrix version of any given network: http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/adjexporter.